# numpy.vectorize returns incorrect values

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I am having some problems with the `numpy.vectorize` function.

I have defined a function that works well for single element input but the vectorized version returns different results - What am I doing wrong?

**Code:**

```
def c_inf_comp(z):
    if z>0:
        return np.exp(-1./(z*z))
    else:
        return 0


>>> x = np.array([-10., 10.])
>>> x
array([-10.,  10.])
>>> c_inf_comp(x[0])
0
>>> c_inf_comp(x[1])
0.99004983374916811
>>> vfunz = np.vectorize(c_inf_comp)
>>> vfunz(x)
array([0, 0])
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Because you don't specify `otypes` (the output data type) when you vectorize your function, NumPy assumes you want to return an array of `int32` values.

When given `x` the vectorized function `vfunz` first sees `-10.`, returns the integer `0`, and so decides that the `dtype` of the returned array should be `int32`.

To fix this, specify `otypes` to be `np.float` values:

```
vfunz = np.vectorize(c_inf_comp, otypes=[np.float])
```

You then get your expected result:

```
>>> vfunz(x)
array([ 0.        ,  0.99004983])
```

(Alternatively, the issue can be fixed by returning a float value in the `else` condition of `c_inf_comp`, i.e. `return 0.0`. That way, the function generated by `np.vectorize(c_inf_comp)` will return an array of float values even if it sees a negative number first.)

Comment: This little issue caused me a lot of time waste... Here's another example explaining the situation: https://gist.github.com/drorata/dd9028c993b676328001c414ce822385

Comment: Why would this be the default behavior?