# Python - expanding numpy array changes all values of vectorized function

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I am noticing some odd behavior when trying to vectorize the following bump function.  It should return positive values for any inputs in the open interval (-1,1), and return 0 for inputs elsewhere:

```
>>import numpy as np

>>def bump(x):
    if np.abs(x)<1:
        return np.exp(-1/(1-x**2))
    else:
        return 0

>>vbump=np.vectorize(bump)
```

When I then try to evaluate the function `vbump` on an array which contains only values in (-1,1) it behaves as expected:

```
>>x=np.linspace(-0.99,0.99,10)
>>vbump(x)

array([  1.50022600e-22,   8.57431637e-02,   2.38427081e-01,
     3.25559999e-01,   3.63401061e-01,   3.63401061e-01,
     3.25559999e-01,   2.38427081e-01,   8.57431637e-02,
     1.50022600e-22])
```

On the other hand, when I try to evaluate it on an array which contains values outside of (-1,1) I get all zeros, even for the values which should be positive:

```
>>x2=np.linspace(-1.1,1.1,10)
>>vbump(x2)

array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Why is it behaving like this?  I'm fairly new to python and numpy, but from my understanding when I vectorize a function it should allow the function to be threaded over lists element-wise.  Why is putting a larger array in affecting the element-wise evaluations elsewhere?

I should add that I have found a solution to the immediate problem of evaluating the bump function over an array, using

```
>>np.piecewise(x, [x <=-1, x >= 1,(-1<x)&(x<1)], [0,0,lambda t:np.exp(-1/(1-t**2))])
```

but I'd still like to understand what is going on with my initial approach.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26316357/numpy-vectorize-returns-incorrect-values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the documentation for `np.vectorize` explains:

> The data type of the output of `vectorized` is determined by calling the function with the first element of the input.  This can be avoided by specifying the `otypes` argument.

When the first value is -1.1, the returned value of your function is an integer 0, and so the dtype becomes an integer dtype (the specifics will depend upon your setup; with me it's int32):

```
>>> vbump(np.array([-0.99]))
array([  1.50022600e-22])
>>> vbump(np.array([-0.99])).dtype
dtype('float64')
>>> vbump(np.array([-1.0]))
array([0])
>>> vbump(np.array([-1.0])).dtype
dtype('int32')
```

Either change your `0` to `0.0` (so you're always returning a float), or specify `otypes`:

```
>>> vbump = np.vectorize(bump, otypes=[float])
>>> vbump(np.linspace(-1.1, 1.1, 10))
array([ 0.        ,  0.02396887,  0.20269374,  0.31495442,  0.36234271,
        0.36234271,  0.31495442,  0.20269374,  0.02396887,  0.        ])
```