# Apply a function to numpy array in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to apply a function to every element of numpy array along with few parameters.

```
def wcdf(u, A, k):
    if(u > 0):
        y=(1 - np.exp(-(u/A)**(k)));
        return y
    else:
        return(0)
```

I don't know what I am missing but whenever array has a `0` it returns `0` for every element.

```
f=np.vectorize(wcdf)
u=f(np.array([1,2]),10,2);
print(u)
```

> Result : [ 0.00995017  0.03921056]

The above works fine, but when I have a zero then:

```
u=f(np.array([0,2]),10,2);
print(u)
```

> Result : [0 0]

Can somebody point out what am I doing wrong!!!!

Thanks

Comment: in the function `wcdf`, if `u` is an array, you cannot do `if(u>0)`. It should return the error `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Comment: @Siladittya, wcdf, u is not an array.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26316780/3941704) seems to solve your pb (Upvote there).
Add `otypes` like `np.vectorize(wcdf, otypes=[np.float])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try passing the array as `np.float32`

```
import numpy as np
def wcdf(U, A, k):
    return np.array([1 - np.exp(-(u/A)**(k)) if u >0 else 0 for u in U])


u=wcdf(np.array([0,2],dtype=np.float32),10,2);
print(u)
```

My result:

`[ 0.          0.03921056]`

Using your method using `np.vectorize`

```
import numpy as np
def wcdf(u, A, k):
    return 1 - np.exp(-(u/A)**(k)) if u >0 else 0

f = np.vectorize(wcdf,otypes=[float])
u=f(np.array([0,2],dtype=np.float32),10,2);
print(u)
```

Result:

`[ 0.          0.03921056]`

You have add the `otypes` as `float`